# How do I split up a sprite sheet for interface, then increase the size of the sprite?

Tags: html, css, image, sprite

I have a sprite sheet with all the interfaces, and I was able to show the full interface item I need, but I can only figure out how to make it as big as the original.

```
.equipped_weapon_img{
    background-image:url("./interface.png");
    width: 46px;
    height: 41px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-position: -1px -44px;
}
```

How can I make it so this image takes up the whole space of the div its on and not just 46px x 41 px?

I know normally you'd just set the picture and then set height and width to 100% but since I'm cutting it out from a sprite sheet, how can I do this?

Comment: would it be better off if I just rendered it on canvas?

Comment: Still haven't been able to figure it out